# R wild single character in replace sub

Tags: r

how I can refer to any single character in R>? in my case it would be 3 any chars. I bit overwhelmed with its power, so many help around !) In my case I need to replace any 3 characters in pos 25-27 with "XXX".  I successfully used this code to replace specific chars, tried to use %,* instead of abc with no avail.  Tx much

```
d <- c("alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_abc v3")
sub("^(.{24})abc", "\\1XXX", d)
   [1] "alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_XXX v3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways, using pattern `"^(.{24}).{3}"` or using `substring` :

```
d <- c("alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_abc v3")
sub("^(.{24}).{3}", "\\1XXX", d)
#> [1] "alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_XXX v3"

d <- c("alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_abc v3")
substring(d, 25, 27) <- "XXX"
d
#> [1] "alpha 1 bravo 0 charlie_XXX v3"
```

Comment: I think `substring` is the much better option here, it does it much more directly, and probably much more efficiently than using what ends up being a pretty pointless regex.

Comment: @Marius, I initially thought that `substring` would be faster too. But when I do a benchmark, I was surprised that the speed of the two way is similar.

Comment: Tx MT and Marius.

Comment: Sorry Mt, I tried to use with loading data from file and got just a single "XXX". Is there any diff when work with loading file ??  `> z <- readLines("C:\\R\\MX1_V2x.txt")
> z1 <- substring(z, 102, 103) <- "00"          
> z1
[1] "00"`

Comment: Is there any secret, it's just a txt file no any special chars.

Comment: @MikeS, `substring(z, 102, 103) <- "00"` will change `z` directly. Don't do `z1 <- `. Alternatively, `z1 <- z; substring(z1, 102, 103) <- "00"` if you want to keep original `z`.

Comment: Or if it is based on the `_`  `sub("_\\w+", "_XXX", d)`